# WinRT - finger/mouse position

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, position, winrt-xaml

I got a `Canvas` with XAML Elements on it from an external framework so the `Canvas` is like a black box for me. If i press on a control an event is raised with an `EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs  e)` ... I do need to show a `Popup` control at the position where I clicked at...

Now I'm questioning myself where I could get the position I tapped at from ?!?? 
Is there an easy way to get the position ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there are a lot of unknowns in your question - you don't mention what event is raised for example, but you could get the sender of the event and cast it to a `UIElement` or some other expected type, then you can call something like this to extract the position of the element.

```
var position = element
    .TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content)
    .TransformPoint(new Point());
```

To get the actual position of the touch or mouse key press - you can either try subscribing to a `PointerPressed` event on the base canvas and then replace `new Point()` in that code above with the position you got or if the event doesn't bubble up (your handler doesn't get invoked) - you can navigate the visual tree (using `VisualTreeHelper`) and try to subscribe to that event on the child elements of that `Canvas`.

Comment: finally i got my pointer where i pressed at :) now i am questioning myself how i can position my panel inside my grid at the pointers coords. i got the pointer relative to my grid already.